# Problems after using numpy.savetxt

Tags: numpy, python-2.7

i am programming with Python.
this is my code:

```
def data_exp(nr, nc):
    data=numpy.zeros((nr, nc))
    print data
    for i in range(0, nr):
        for j in range (0, nc):
            data[i, j]=input('Insert values: ')
    numpy.savetxt(str(input('Insert the name of the file (ex: "a.txt"): ')), data)
    return data
```

the problem is that this program returns nothing! everything i put after the numpy.savetxt is ignored! can someone tell me how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the inappropriate use of `input`. `input` is the equivalent of `eval(raw_input())`. The `eval()` call will try and evaluate the text you input as python source code in the context of globals and locals within your program, which is clearly not want you want to do in this case. I am surprised you are not getting a runtime error reporting that the string you enter is not defined.

Try using `raw_input` instead:

```
def data_exp(nr, nc):
    data=numpy.zeros((nr, nc))
    print data
    for i in range(0, nr):
        for j in range (0, nc):
            data[i, j]=input('Insert values: ')
    numpy.savetxt(str(raw_input('Insert the name of the file (ex: "a.txt"): ')), data)
    return data
```

---

EDIT:

Here is the code above, working for me in an ipython session. If you cannot get it to work, something else is wrong:

```
In [7]: data_exp(2,2)
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
Insert values: 1
Insert values: 2
Insert values: 3
Insert values: 4
Insert the name of the file (ex: "a.txt"): a.txt
Out[7]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.]])

In [8]: data_exp??
Type:       function
Base Class: <type 'function'>
String Form:    <function data_exp at 0x2ad3070>
Namespace:  Interactive
File:       /Users/talonmies/data_exp.py
Definition: data_exp(nr, nc)
Source:
def data_exp(nr, nc):
    data=numpy.zeros((nr, nc))
    print data
    for i in range(0, nr):
        for j in range (0, nc):
            data[i, j]=input('Insert values: ')
    numpy.savetxt(str(raw_input('Insert the name of the file (ex: "a.txt"): ')), data)
    return data

In [9]: _ip.system("cat a.txt")
1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00
```

Comment: i tried but still it does nothing after the numpy.savetxt: everything i ask it to do after that is ignored!

Comment: ok! it seems i have some problems with python... i decided to do this: 
def data_exp(nr, nc):
    data=np.zeros((nr, nc))
    for i in range(0, nr):
        for j in range (0, nc):
            data[i, j]=raw_input('Insert value: ')
    print data
    print 'To save array digit save(data) and insert name'
    return data

def save(data):
    np.savetxt(str(input('Insert name of the list(ex: a.txt): ')), data)

Comment: here's a try

>>>array=data_exp(3,2)
insert...(i won't write all of it)
[[ 4.  3.]
 [ 2.  3.]
 [ 2.  2.]]
To save array digit save(name_file) and insert name.
>>> save(array)
Insert list name 'list_1.txt'

Done